# UnicodeDecodeError when reading a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, unicode, utf-8, decode

I have a problem when reading a csv file.
I am trying to fill my arrays from the rows of the csv file and I get this error :

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 38: invalid continuation byte
```

Here are my csv file and my code : 
[image]

```
import csv

A=[]
T=[]

with open("classeur_test.csv",'r') as csvfile:
    reader=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader :
        A.append(float(row[0]))
        T.append(float(row[1]))
```

Do you know why ?

Comment: The Same code is working fine in my system with Python 3 on a similar csv file. Please check the format of csv file that you are using or Test with some other csv file.

Comment: For this kind of problem we need to know the *exact* contents of the file, and the graphic does not show that. Please show a hex dump of the first 40 bytes or so of the file. If you do not know how to do that, upload your file somewhere and include a link so we can download the file and examine it more closely. Without that we can only guess.

Comment: Try changing the encoding to latin or any other and read the file

Comment: Ask the author of the file which character encoding they chose. (Any examination by us would still be guessing because there is always more than one possibility. You guess something that acceptable to you now but then it might not be for the next version of the file unless you pick the same one the author picks.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just have to be careful about the delimiter when I open the csv file and in my code.